# sample size to detect variability in a sample

Tags: t-test, sample-size, monte-carlo

I have a sample of continuous data which I use to build a random forest model. Now I want to determine, how many additional samples I would need to improve the prediction (reduce the RMSE by a certain value). 
How many samples do I need to characterize the variability within the population? I can also divide my sample into classes to detect how many samples I would need for each class in order to represent the variability, right?

What Algorithm should I use to estimate the sample size needed to improve my model? Would the one-sample t-test be useful on that issue? Or maybe a Monte Carlo simulation?